In mongo database, when saving NaN for few JSON properties converted to null automatically
I need to store value as NaN for few JSON properties. When I save it Mongodb automatically converted to null.
how to stop this behavior.
Code snippet:
Mongo db Model class :
import mongoose, { Schema } from "mongoose";

const prodSchema = new Schema({
  productName: String,
  oppId: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,

// I am saving in fron-end as NaN type but in database its getting saved as null
  isNaNOrNot: String,  
 
  createdById: String,
  createdBy: String,
}, { strict: false} );

export const Product = mongoose.model("Product", productSchema);


What do you expect? There is no NaN in MongoDB BSON types. The closest is null.

@ray thanks, am using ag-grid react to show product data. User wanted to enter 0 in that grid so i made rowData default value as NaN, later user can enter 0 that can store it in to mongodb, All of suddden when i save it to db and reiterate the page the cell values are started showing null. I started debugging and could not figure out why all are showed as null. later i reliased i could not store NAN then i used valueFormater to display it as emply cell

NaN is not a valid BSON Type, Ref : Valid BSON Types.
That is why it is converted to null on storing in database.
Since the isNaNOrNot field is already of type String, if you wish to store NaN as a value, you should store it as the string "NaN"

thanks for your time , Yes as you said, its not a valid JSON. Later I modified the logic at front end
